# What is the time complexity for loop?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

```
def f2(lst):
  i = len(lst)
  while i>0:
     for j in range(i, i+10**8):
         for k in range(i):
            print(k)
      i -= 2
```

What is the time complexity? while will operate n/2 times, but what about the rest?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about algorithm analysis, not practical programming problems.

Comment: This would be more appropriate on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Maybe try cleverly rephrasing your problem to fit the criteria

Answer (score 2):

The answer is is `O(n^2)`.

The first loop is ~n, the second takes constant time, and the third is ~n.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the `while` loop will iterate `n/2` times and so has `O(n)` complexity.

The first `for` loop (`for j in range(i, i+10**8)`) has constant runtime `O(1)`.

The second `for` loop has complexity `O(n)` and will execute `n+n^2` passes.

This gives the code `O(n^2)` complexity